# How to limit the width/height of svg in pygal

Tags: python, pygal

How do I limit the width/height of a `pygal` generated SVG? I'm currently doing it via `img` tags, but is there a better way?

```
<img src="http://localhost/images/Store.Diapers.svg" width=800 height=600/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps someone, it's as simple as specifying width=1000, height=800 in the parameters:

```
chart = pygal.StackedLine(width=1000, height=800)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div for that....

Place the following in your code:

```
<div class="parent">    
   <img src="http://localhost/images/Store.Diapers.svg">    
</div>
```

And place this in your .css file

```
.imagebox {
width: 42px; /*This is the height of the div class it self */
height: 42px;
}

/* This changes the height of any image with the <img> tag within the div class*/
.imagebox img {
height: 800px;
width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthijs, its essentially accomplishing the same thing. I am looking for a non-css/html solution native to pygal.

Comment: But why don't you want to use CSS/HTML?

Comment: I usually prefer native solutions with html around it for my own presentation layer, so i'll use it if i have to. so hence my question to the ether.